# How to save DropdownButtonFormField value to Firebase real-time database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, drop-down-menu

I'm using firebase real-time database and I have a form where the user adds the information to the database using it, but I'm stuck with the DropdownButtonFormField, how can I store the value in my database when the form button is pressed?
I used to use the controller when it was TextFormField, but now, I don't know what to do

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(width: 2, color: appColor),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Location',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          // Initial Value
                          value: selectedLocation,
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                            color: appColor,
                          ),
                          // Array list of items
                          items: Locations.map((String items) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: items,
                              child: Text(items),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          // After selecting the desired option,it will
                          // change button value to selected value
                          onChanged: (String? newLocation) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedLocation = newLocation!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you get the selectedLocation value and pass that to firebase method. print selectedLocation in the onChange method then when ever you click item in dropdown, the selectedLocation will change.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");

await ref.set({
  "selectedLocation": selectedLocation ,
});
```